# Getting Index of Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, indexing

```
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s1 ="Test1";
    String s2 ="Test2";
    str.add(s1);
    str.add(s2);
```

I want to compare a string to one of the elements of the array.

```
    String b = "Test1";

    b.equals(str[index??]);
```

How can i get the index of str?

Comment: `str.get(index);` since it's an ArrayList. WHERE INDEX is an INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an arrayList. Therefore, to store a value of the array with a certain index, use this:

```
ArrayList.get(index);
```

Now, you can make this equal to a variable like this:

```
 String mStr = ArrayList.get(index);
```

If I have an arrayList with the values `"1, 2, 3, 4"` it's important to note, index 0 is the value 1.

```
ArrayList.get(0) //HERE, THE INDEX IS ZERO, MEANING THE VALUE OF THE ARRAY LIST WOULD BE 1
```

**Output:**
1

---

That is easily confused; index 0 = first value. Just be sure to use the get() method.

To further compare strings, set that values equal to strings:

```
 String FIRSTSTRING= ArrayList.get(0);
 String SECONDSTRING= ArrayList.get(1);
```

**Here, I am comparing the first and second values of the array list.**

If you found this helpful, mark it as best answer. If you need more help, feel free to ask me, I am always happy to help!

```
{Ruchir}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    boolean found = false;
    for(String string : str)
    found =b.equals(string);
```

Other than that,you can use [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) method of list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Binary Search if your Array is sorted. Otherwise, just go linearly in the arraylist, and compare the values.

in your case:

```
boolean find = false;
for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(str.get(i) == b){
       find = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`List.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) (where `int` is the index). For example,

```
List<String> al = Arrays.asList("Test1", "Test2");
System.out.println(al.get(0).equals("Test1"));
```

the output is

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` method.

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
String s1 ="Test1";
String s2 ="Test2";
str.add(s1);
str.add(s2);

System.out.println(str.indexOf("Test1"));
```

---

If you want to use the str.get(index) method and then check use a loop, But I find this more complicated.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
  if(list.get(i).equals("rtes"))
    return i;
```